# ViewState on control inside page header

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, header, viewstate

I'm adding my js files to header on code-behind like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            js.Attributes["src"] = "/js/jquery.js";
            js.ID = "jquery";
            js.EnableViewState = true;
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(js);
        }
}
```

this works pretty well on page load, but I lose my js on postbacks, I was expecting my control persist with  HtmlGenericControl's ViewState enabled...

any way to persist ViewState on header or do I have to remove   `if (!IsPostBack)` condition to add js every time?

Comment: P.S. anyway, beside my answer below, this is surely not the common way to include jquery in aspx pages!

Comment: I know is not common but I need to because of dynamic purposes, certain js files should be included for certain jquery plugins but they may be included before by another plugin

Comment: then you should probably do it with the script manager or in the proper way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your control is added dynamically and only when `!IsPostBack`, ViewState can keep values and status but the control has to exists by its own on the page.

In your case after a post back the control will not be added so even if the `ViewState` contained its status, there is no control to attach this status to.

Comment: I've tried using a placeholder or attaching js files to my master page  header content with no success, so it seems there's no Viewstate on header at all